# What is the name for a torture device that uses electricity to make the victim suffer?

Tags: names

What is the name for a torture device that uses electricity to make the victim suffer? Not as powerful as an electric chair that kills the victim outright but something which makes him suffer for a long period of time.

Comment: Probably most torturers don't know the word either, so when they're out shopping for the tools of their trade they just buy a [***cattle prod***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle_prod)

Comment: Jinx! @FumbleFingers - Gotta wake early to beat you Brits.

Comment: I think it's called "YouTube".

Comment: @HotLicks I was going to say Local Radio

Comment: @PhilMJones - Certainly there's a morning sports show that would qualify.

Answer (score 4):

It is *[picana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picana)*; the picana is the device used to give an electric shock during electrical torture.It is more painful than burning but unlike burning it does not leave scars and unlike other electric devices it does not stun or kill.

Being a torture victim myself (April-May 1981) and a many-years [Amnesty-International](http://www.amnesty.org/)-member activist against torture am "familiar" with these issues if you will.In a Jungian [synchronicity](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=synchronicity) , during my study in USA when I was still having sleep disturbance due to this [profound](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what%20is%20profound%20mean&revid=869144622) experience,  that good psychiatrist I consulted turned out to be a Jewish survivor of a [Nazi concentration camp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_concentration_camps).

Comment: Good word. Good answer. Plus 1.

Answer (score 3):

**Cattle prod**

> As the precursor of stun guns, cattle prods also have a wide range of voltage with enough amperage to operate in the same manner as a stun gun does against humans. A stun gun is nothing more than a beefed up cattle prod and both can be used on humans or animals by design.
>
> **Wikipedia**

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to a [stun gun](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stun+gun):

> - A weapon designed to stun or temporarily immobilize a victim, especially by delivering a high-voltage electric shock.

(TFD)

[image]